# Set several tag attributes at once using a variable in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I am migrating some JSP files to Thymeleaf and I have found the following problem. In the original JSP code there is a file that is included in lots of other JSP files that has a line like the following:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="data-x=50 data-y=37" />
```

In the files which include this one the variable `myVar` is used like this:

```
<div class="myClass" ${myVar}>
```

setting several attributes that are used everywhere all at once. The main point here is that you set up `myVar` in one file and its values are used in all other files. If you need to change the value of the attributes you only need to change one file.

Trying to replicate this in Thymeleaf, I tried using the `th:attr` attribute in the following way. First, I set a variable in the model like this:

```
model.addAttribute("myVar", "data-x=50, data-y=37");
```

and then in Thymeleaf I do:

```
<div class="myClass" th:attr="${myVar}" >
```

but it does not work, it throws

```
TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "${myVar}"
```

I've also have thought of using Javascript to add the attributes dynamically using JQuery, but I would prefer to do it in other way, since I did not built the application, it has a lot of scripting and I fear doing it through Javascript can have side effects.

Is there any way I can write directly in the HTML output using Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this with preprocessing.  Something like this will work with your example:

```
<div class="myClass" th:attr="__${myVar}__" />
```

(This does rely on `${myVar}` being a valid string for the th:attr property, so you'll have to be careful with it.)